# How to keep vim quickfix window or buffer opened all the time

Tags: vim, vim-quickfix

I use quickfix window only for cscope. I would like to keep this open all the time. Currently quickfix window gets closed whenever there is a change in the file during cnext or cprev. I have tried location list too for cscope buffers. But that too gets closed on change of file during lnext and lprev. I have only these cscope/quickfix settings

```
set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-,a-
set cscopetag cscopeverbose 
set csto=1 cst
```

How to keep quickfix window open all the time? Even when there is a change in file while doing cnext or cprev.

Comment: What you want is the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you @romainl. After your answer I re-looked at my config and then found this "set switchbuf=useopen,usetab,newtab". I am ashamed to say I should have done this before asking. Thanks again.